# написание правил для adblock firefox

Tags: firefox, youtube

`youtube.com###secondary-inner
youtube.com##.style-scope.ytd-two-column-browse-results-renderer
youtube.com##.html5-endscreen.ytp-player-content.videowall-endscreen.ytp-show-tiles.ytp-endscreen-paginate`

Написал несколько правил для adblock + firefox
Первое удаляет правую колонку при просмотре некого видео.
Второе на главной странице удаляет все предлагаемые видео.
Третья удаляет предлагаемые видео после завершения просмотра видео.

если я зайду в некий канал Youtube сторым правилом блокируются все видео на канале.
Мне нужно написать исключение, чтобы на каналах видео не блокировались.
Уже пробовал следующие способы:

`youtube.com,~youtube.com/channel##.style-scope.ytd-two-column-browse-results-renderer`
В этом случае видео не блокируются на главной странице и на каналах тоже.

`youtube.com,##.style-scope.ytd-two-column-browse-results-renderer
@@||youtube.com/channel`
В этом случае блокируется на главной и на каналах тоже.

Помогите исправить второе правилио.
Либо дописать отдельное правило исключение.
В результате нужно чтобы на главной странице youtube я видел только строку поиска:
http://i7.5cm.ru/i/iq6O.jpg
А на каналах ютюба чтобы видео не блокировалось и все показывалось:
http://i7.5cm.ru/i/Pxqo.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
youtube.com###secondary-inner  
youtube.com##ytd-section-list-renderer[page-subtype="home"].style-scope.ytd-two-column-browse-results-renderer  
youtube.com##.ytp-endscreen-content  
youtube.com##.ytp-ce-element.ytp-ce-video.ytp-ce-element-show  
youtube.com##.ytp-ce-element.ytp-ce-channel.ytp-ce-channel-this.ytp-ce-element-show
```

Первая удаляет правую колонку при просмотре некого видео.
Второе на главной странице удаляет все предлагаемые видео.
Третья удаляет предлагаемые видео после завершения просмотра видео.
Четвертая удаляет различные предлогаемые видео поверх видео до завершения просмотра.
Пятая удаляет поверх видео предложение подписаться.